# A pattern to identify content of a csv file in JavaScript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, csv

I have CSV files in different formats. What I'd like to do, is identify the file based on the content, and then parse the file and put each row into different database tables.

I'm wondering if anyone has ever done anything like this before, and if so, how you went about it. If anyone can suggest anything or post a link to any content that might help, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have some example lines?

Comment: If you're using javascript, try using a library such as http://papaparse.com/demo

With this, you can easily send the array to your php backend as json, which can parse and insert the rows into your tables.

Comment: As per I can understand, If you have patterns then you should use loop with switch statement for each type of pattern and send data to required table. You can have a look to PHPExcel ('https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel') for parsing csv files